# Не получается установить dotenv: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'. macOS

Tags: python, macos

Перепробовал все варианты установки, с флагом -m, через анаконду, переустанавливал, но ничего не помогает. macOS.

Comment: Вы пробовали команду со [страницы проекта](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) на Pypi: `pip install python-dotenv`?

Comment: Уже есть ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1495960/507426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в версии питона, я то скачал ее, но не выбрал в VScode

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже есть, но я его нагло сворую:

> О, так это потому что модуль называется python-dotenv, а не dotenv.
> Установите его командой pip install python-dotenv, и всё получится.

Вот ссылка на оригинал: [ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1495960/507426](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1495960/507426)